# How to use Duplicator plugin to carefully migrate the old site URL to new URL in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, web, database-migration, http-status-code-301, web-development-server

I'm planning to 301 redirect my entire site to the new domain to keep the SEO reserve. (I have bought a domain from GoDaddy and added to Hostgator using nameserver )

I'm using WordPress duplicator to build the duplicate package to migrate my old site data to new URL.

**But there are some questions:**

> My site is on shared hosting. And there is another site on my server.
> I want to exclude it. How can I do to make sure that another site is
> purely excluded?
>
> Why am I getting 'size notice' while creating duplicator package using
> the 'duplicator' plugin? how can I fix it?
>
> Can I use add SSL certificate to my new domain before migrating? Because my old site didn't have any HTTPS or SSL certificate.
>
> I installed SiteLock with older site's URL to protect my site from any malware attack. What would happen, if I change my Domain? Do I need to do something?
>
> What about CDN that I already installed with the older domain. Do I need to reinstall or configure again after redirecting to the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

i will try to answer some of your questions:

How can I do to make sure that another site is purely excluded?

if you are hosting this website on Hostgator. there is a section called "website essentials" under this section you will find "my installs" and there you will find the website hosted there. you can still keep it if its hosted on another domain but you can delete if you want to.

Why am I getting 'size notice' while creating duplicator package using the 'duplicator' plugin? how can I fix it?

check the php.ini for the size notice. it can be that there are some size limitation: check those parameters: 
upload_max_filesize,  post_max_size.

Can I use add SSL certificate to my new domain before migrating? Because my old site didn't have any HTTPS or SSL certificate.

you can add an ssl later on to your website so you dont have to worry about that. 
hope this help